# Instrução DELETE não apaga pelo php mas pelo phpmyadmin a instrução funciona

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte codigo onde estou a tentar apagar uma coluna da bd atravès de php :

```
session_start();
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=samsic', 'root', '');

$sql = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM ferias WHERE id=':i' and idtrabalhador=':it' ");
$sql->bindValue(':i',$_GET['id']);
$sql->bindValue(':it',$_SESSION['id']);
$resultado=$sql->execute();

if($resultado){
    echo "Apagou";
}else{
    echo "não apagou";
}
```

O código retorna-me sempre "Apagou" mas ele não apaga nada na base de dados. 
Por outro lado, se copiar a instrução sql que tenho no php no mysql e substituir pelos mesmos valores ela vai funcionar correctamente e apagar a coluna.

Alguem me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Tirei as '' dos valores a receber da query e funcionou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você colocou as aspas simples o comando SQL passa a considerar o valor como um VARCHAR, caso o tipo das tuplas seja diferente de VARCHAR ou um DATE, um INT por exemplo, não deve ser colocado as aspas.
Quando tiver alguma dúvida da execução de um SQL basta testar no próprio console do phpmyadmin.